# The strange behavior of Object.entries

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I ran into strange behavior while using the standard `Object.entries` method. The bug appears only on production (webpack build).

[image: screenshot of my console]

Description

- My `this.props` contains some fields with function-values
- Standard Chrome `Object.entries` method returns a strange result: I get duplicated function names instead of real functions
- If I try to use `Object.entries` to copy `this.props` ― nothing changes
- If I try to mix the copied object with any random field then `Object.entries` works properly (I get real functions as a value in result arrays)

Do I misunderstand `Object.entries` mechanism? Or is it a Chrome bug? I can't reproduce it in Firefox. Also I don't understand how to reproduce it anywhere (except that my prod-page)... So I can't place here a working js-sandbox.

If it is a Chrome bug, what I should to do? Register an issue anywhere? Make a browser-tab dump?

Comment: http://ftp.faiwer.ru/img_20_03_19%3A10%3A20_4ea8b8207a7.png one more screenshot of this issue :)

Comment: please post the relevant code here

Comment: maybe something mutated props inbetween?

Comment: @messerbill I have no idea how to get a relevant code with this problem. Sorry. It looks like this object has a bit of magic.

Comment: the relevant code is the code you have written to solve the issue

Comment: but I can run in console any debug-code with this object. This tab is opened and I play with it in the console of devtools

Comment: @messerbill I didn't solve the issue yet :) I can do it easily avoding `Object.entries`. But I wanna understand what this problem is. May be I don't know something important about javascript objects or standart JS library.

Comment: @JonasW. The JS thread is stopped manually. I set several breakpoints, debugged them and finally have caught the "bug". And it's a strange "bug". I can play with it in the console, but I don't know its nature, so I don't know how to reproduce it in external js-sandbox.

Comment: i guess `this.props` is related to React? if so, maybe its some part of react that does this.

Comment: @JonasW. you're right. It's a prod-react object. Maybe its a something with React there.

Comment: @JonasW. it looks like common basic object. http://ftp.faiwer.ru/img_20_03_19%3A26%3A48_32ee2f08351.png . It have a standart `__proto__` and it don't have any custom iterators.

Comment: http://ftp.faiwer.ru/img_20_03_19%3A28%3A40_661b9c0c397.png wow. It's much more interesting. `Object.values` returns these strings too. Instead of methods.

Comment: But `for in` cycle works properly: http://ftp.faiwer.ru/img_20_03_19%3A30%3A17_d3b704082bf.png . It shows the methods.

Comment: `this.props[Symbol.iterator] === undefined` :)

Comment: @faiwerfaiwe sure cause its not an array. its either a react thing or some bug in chrome

Comment: I don't understand how React can do it. May be React do it, but how? http://ftp.faiwer.ru/img_20_03_19%3A38%3A38_f2ce580ffaf.png <== no custom symbols, no custom __proto__. Hm. Funny :)

Comment: Can you still reproduce it on current Chrome?

Comment: @Ry no, I can't

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too. I've used this chrome (just for Android) version to reproduce that: https://chrome.en.uptodown.com/android/download/1714050

I was using this Immutable HOC (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.md#use-a-higher-order-component-to-convert-your-smart-components-immutablejs-props-to-your-dumb-components-javascript-props) as a 'toJS' utils when I got it, and I just changed to use another approach, something like using 'Object.keys' and '.map'...

And it can be relevant for you too: https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/issues/370